# vue 3 radio button revert back if user canceled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am having some issues with some radio buttons in vue 3

From the parent component I am passing an object to the child where is the data displayed and where I want to make one version default:

```
<template>
    <table>
        ...
        <tr v-for="(vf, index) in version.files" :key="vf.id">
         ...
         <td>
            <input type="radio" name="defaultVersion" v-model="vf.default" :checked="vf.default" @change="onChangeDefault(index)" @click="onClickDefault">
         </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>

props: {
    version: Object // the prop object received
},

setup(props) {
    const {version} = toRefs(props) // version should be now reactive
    
    // use this variable to know where is the index that contains the default value
    let defaultVersionIndex = 0
    
    const onClickDefault = () => {
        // check on click what is the current version default and store the index
        for(let i = 0; i < version.value.files.length; i++) {
            if(version.value.files[i].default) {
                defaultVersionIndex = i
            }
        }
    }
    
    const onChangeDefault = (index) => {
        let text = "Change default?\nEither OK or Cancel.";
        if (confirm(text) == true) {
          // user press ok => make API call
        } else {
          // if the user canceled => set the default radio checked (previously)
          version.value.files[index].default = false // change back from what user has selected
          version.value.files[defaultVersionIndex].default = true // set back the original radio checked (previously)
        }
    }
    
    return {
        version,
        onClickDefault,
        onChangeDefault
    }
}
```

When click on a radio (unchecked) it changes visually - but in the version.files no changes ... what I am missing ???

You get the idea .... when the user cancel the action to revert back the radio button. I choose radio because only one can be default.

**UPDATE 1**

make some changes on input by binding the value (to make sure the value is boolean not on, off)

```
<input type="radio" :value="vf.default" name="defaultVersion" v-model="vf.default" :checked="vf.default" @change="onChangeDefault(index)" @click="onClickDefault">
```

and on canceled action :

```
version.value.files[index].default = !version.value.files[index].default
version.value.files[defaultVersionIndex].default = !version.value.files[defaultVersionIndex].default
```

the values in the object version.files now changes but visually not working like it should...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

On input:

```
<input type="radio" :value="vf.id" name="defaultVersion" v-model="defaultValue" :checked="vf.id === defaultValue" @change="onChangeDefault(vf.id)" @click="onClickDefault">
```

Created a vmodel that hold the id for the default value

```
const defaultValue = ref(0)

// store the previous default value (id)
let previousDefault = 0
const onClickDefault = () => {
 previousDefault = defaultValue.value // this is the magic :)
}
```

the when the user canceled:

```
defaultValue.value = previousDefault
```